# PHP Multi-Dimensional Array w/Parent ID to Category Taxonomy Array, Ebay Style

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration, ebay-api

Going for days now, ready to quit. I make a call to eBay's trading API to return a list of categories. The array below shows how these categories are returned from the API. I am trying like hell to arrange it into a taxonomy like the first gray box below.

Do note that the number at the beginning of each line is the id of the final category for that particular line.

```
3270: Vehicle Electronics & GPS
175716: Vehicle Electronics & GPS > Car Audio
18805: Vehicle Electronics & GPS > Car Audio > Car Subwoofers
18795: Vehicle Electronics & GPS > Car Audio > Car Amplifiers
39754: Vehicle Electronics & GPS > Car Audio > Car Audio In-Dash Units
```

I have greatly shortened this array to one example. Many categories will be pumped through to build the taxonomy.

The CategoryLevel can start at any number and it can end at any number. In this example, it starts at 2 and the highest level is 4.

```
Array
(
    [3270] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 3270
            [CategoryLevel] => 2
            [CategoryName] => Vehicle Electronics & GPS
            [CategoryParentID] => 293
        )

    [175716] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 175716
            [CategoryLevel] => 3
            [CategoryName] => Car Audio
            [CategoryParentID] => 3270
        )


    [79839] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 79839
            [CategoryLevel] => 4
            [CategoryName] => Signal Processors
            [CategoryParentID] => 175716
            [LeafCategory] => true
        )

    [18805] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 18805
            [CategoryLevel] => 4
            [CategoryName] => Car Subwoofers
            [CategoryParentID] => 175716
            [LeafCategory] => true
        )

    [18795] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 18795
            [CategoryLevel] => 4
            [CategoryName] => Car Amplifiers
            [CategoryParentID] => 175716
            [LeafCategory] => true
        )

    [39754] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 39754
            [CategoryLevel] => 4
            [CategoryName] => Car Audio In-Dash Units
            [CategoryParentID] => 175716
            [LeafCategory] => true
        )


)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Im trying the code but i received some errors. do you have the chance to share the structure of samplearray.php? thank you! @shawn-abramson

Comment: I unfortunately do not. However, the array that I used is the array in the original question. Add some quotation marks around the array keys and you should be good to go.

Comment: I will try, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Again, fixed error.

```
<?php
require_once("samplearray.php");

function makeNestedData($data){
    //create a nested tree using the above structure
    $nested = array();

    //loop over each category
    foreach($data as &$category){
        //is there is no children array, add it
        if(!isset($category['Children'])){
            $category['Children'] = array();
        }
        //check if there is a matching parent
        if(isset($data[$category['CategoryParentID']])){
            //add this under the parent as a child by reference
            if(!isset($data[$category['CategoryParentID']]['Children'])){
                $data[$category['CategoryParentID']]['Children'] = array();
            }
            $data[$category['CategoryParentID']]['Children'][$category['CategoryID']] = &$category;
        //else, no parent found, add at top level
        } else {
            $nested[$category['CategoryID']] = &$category;
        }
    }
    unset($category);
    return $nested;
}

//now flatten out the nested array recursively
function flattenNested($nested, $parent=''){
    $out = array();
    foreach($nested as $category){
        $categoryName = $parent.$category['CategoryName'];
        $out[$category['CategoryID']] = $categoryName;
        //recurse for each child
        $out += flattenNested($category['Children'], $categoryName.' > ');
    }
    return $out;
}

$result = flattenNested(makeNestedData($array));
print_r($result);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [3270] => Vehicle Electronics & GPS
    [175716] => Vehicle Electronics & GPS > Car Audio
    [79839] => Vehicle Electronics & GPS > Car Audio > Signal Processors
    [18805] => Vehicle Electronics & GPS > Car Audio > Car Subwoofers
    [18795] => Vehicle Electronics & GPS > Car Audio > Car Amplifiers
    [39754] => Vehicle Electronics & GPS > Car Audio > Car Audio In-Dash Units
)
```

Output is an array with the right side category id as the key and the value is a string with category text.

This may seem like a complicated or unnecessary way to do this, but this is really one of the better ways IMO because it will handle any order for the categories and any number of nested levels. The only limit would have to do with the recursion and possibly memory but I tried to use references where possible to keep that memory footprint as small as possible.

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Fke5OA

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you for making the effort. However, you processed the data in reverse. I apologize if I wasn't clearer but I want to turn the array into the 18805: Vehicle Electronics & GPS > Car Audio > Car Subwoofers

Comment: Ah, yes. Typically when you ask questions you specify "this is what I have, and this is what I want". I was assuming that was the order because it didn't specifically say which was which other than "ebay style" (whatever that means). I'll write up the reverse real quick.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you again. With my sample array, it works perfectly. With my actual data array, which is simply the same type of array I gave in the sample, but with more groups, it simply produces a flat $key => $value array for the entire thing, Been playing with it for about an hour but having a tough time. Can't figure it out for the life of me, recursion makes me crazy.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Would you share some more data? Perhaps even just more sample data. It doesn't have to be complicated.

Comment: If you have some time. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71539/php-multi-dimensional-array-w-parent-id-to-category-taxonomy-array-ebay-style

Comment: Jonathan, thank you for really taking the time to help me out. This works perfectly for any using the GetCategories call from the eBay trading API.

Comment: It sounds like this issue is addressed sufficiently already, but FWIW, you can get category taxonomy and basic info (name, path, ID#, etc.) via a simpler API call in the Shopping API family: GetCategoryInfo. There may be fewer complications to deal with there. http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetCategoryInfo.html